# Hide page action for specific url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension for reddit.com and I am using `page action` for that. Now I want `page_action icon` to be visible only for a specific url format i.e.

```
http://www.reddit.com   [allowed]
http://www.reddit.com/r/*   [allowed]
http://www.reddit.com/r/books/comments/*   [not allowed]
```

So, as I have mentioned above that I don't want my extension page action icon to be visible for the `3rd case` involving `comments url of redddit` .

Currently I am using the below code in my `background.js` to achieve this:

```
function check(tab_id, data, tab){
    if(tab.url.indexOf("reddit.com") > -1 && tab.url.indexOf("/comments/") == -1){
        chrome.pageAction.show(tab_id);
    }
};
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(check);
```

I have also added the below line in my `manifest.json` to disable the extension on the comment page

```
 "exclude_matches": ["http://www.reddit.com/r/*/comments/*"],
```

So, my question is this the correct/ideal way to disable & hide an extension from a specific page/url?

Answer (score 1):

Why not Zoidb- I mean, Regular Expressions?

```
var displayPageAction = function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    var regex = new RegExp(/.../); //Your regex goes here
    var match = regex.exec(tab.url); 
    // We only display the Page Action if we are inside a tab that matches
    if(match && changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
      chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
    }
};

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(displayPageAction);
```

About the approach, I think using the `onUpdated.addListener` is the correct approach. As a good practice, try to show your page Action only when the tab has been loaded, unless your application requirements specify otherwise.

You can use [this tool](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/) in order to generate your regular expression, and if you need help, feel free to ask again and we will help you assemble the regular expression you need.